# Logstash checking for field existence in nested json

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to check for the MD5 field existence in Logstash 6.4 filter.

```
"files": [
  {
    "SHA256": "DA3662E34C66D770F28D23A26980B31245753049E55B0348D51B22524C00EE1C",
    "filesize": "8732",
    "MD5": "0551229E1E1180F5BF5513222C75412A"
  },
  {
    "SHA256": "ADA57125645BE67E7DB885D4DF8EBBC46B7CA8F54258EEC510ECDCC9350FCB43",
    "filesize": "433433",
    "MD5": "ADF322D0711E22BDFAA60E3503621292"
  }]
```

First tried filter:

```
filter {
if ("" in [files][MD5]) {
    mutate {
     add_field => { "md5_num" => "50"}
    }
}
}
```

Second tried filter:

```
filter {
if [files][MD5]{
    mutate {
     add_field => { "md5_num" => "50"}
    }
}
}
```

How come any of those two filters do not work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `file` contains a json array. So you'd need to use the index of an element of the array for this to work.

```
if [files][0][MD5]{
    mutate {
        add_field => { "md5_num" => "50"}
    }
}
```

Comment: That is correct, I have realized that yesterday. Thanks for your post.